# Stack overflow in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, stack-overflow, fortran90

I have written a fairly large program in Fortran 90. It has been working beautifully for quite a while, but today I tried to step it up a notch and increase the problem size (it is a research non-standard FE-solver, if that helps anyone...) Now I get the "stack overflow" error message and naturally the program terminates without giving me anything useful to work with.

The program starts with setting up all relevant arrays and matrices, and after that is done it prints a few lines of stats regarding this to a log-file. Even with my new, larger problem, this works fine (albeit a little slow), but then it fails as the "number crunching" gets going.

What confuses me is that everything at that point is already allocated (and that worked without errors). I'm not entirely sure what the stack is (Wikipedia and several treads here didn't do much since I have only a quite basic knowledge of the "behind the scenes" workings of a computer).

Assume that I for instance have some arrays initialized as:

```
INTEGER,DIMENSION(64) :: IA
REAL(8),DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: AA, BB
```

which after some initialization routines (i.e. read input from file and such) are allocated as (I store some size-integers for easier passing to subroutines in IA of fixed size):

```
ALLOCATE( AA(N1,N2) , BB(N1,N2) )
IA(1) = N1
IA(2) = N2
```

This is basically what happens in the initial portion, and so far so good. But when I then call a subroutine

```
CALL ROUTINE_ONE(AA,BB,IA)
```

And the routine looks like (nothing fancy):

```
SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_ONE(AA,BB,IA)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,DIMENSION(64) :: IA
REAL(8),DIMENSION(IA(1),IA(2)) :: AA, BB
...
do lots of other stuff
...
END SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_ONE
```

Now I get an error! The output to the screen says:

```
forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow
```

However, when I run the program with the debugger it breaks at line 419 in a file called `winsig.c` (not my file, but probably part of the compiler?). It seems to be part of a routine called `sigreterror:` and it is the default case that has been invoked, returning the text `Invalid signal or error`. There is a comment line attached to this which strangely says `/* should never happen, but compiler can't tell */` ...?

So I guess my question is, why does this happen and what is actually happening? I thought that as long as I can allocate all the relevant memory I should be fine? Does the call to the subroutine make copies of the arguments, or just pointers to them? If the answer is copies then I can see where the problem might be, and if so: any ideas on how to get around it?

The problem I try to solve is big, but not insane in any way. Standard FE-solvers can handle bigger problems than my current one. I run the program on a Dell PowerEdge 1850 and the OS is Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. According to `systeminfo` at the `cmd` prompt I have 8GB of physical memory and almost 16GB virtual. As far as I understand the total of all my arrays and matrices should not add up to more than maybe 100MB - about 5.5M `integer(4)` and 2.5M `real(8)` (which according to me should be only about 44MB, but let's be fair and add another 50MB for overhead).

I use the Intel Fortran compiler integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

---

Adding some actual source code to clarify a bit

```
! Update continuum state
CALL UpdateContinuumState(iTask,iArray,posc,dof,dof_k,nodedof,elm,&
                    bmtrx,detjac,w,mtrlprops,demtrx,dt,stress,strain,effstrain,&
                    effstress,aa,fi,errmsg)
```

is the actual call to the routine. Big arrays are `posc`, `bmtrx` and `aa` - all other are at least an order of magnitude smaller (if not more). `posc` is `INTEGER(4)` and `bmtrx` and `aa` is `REAL(8)`

```
SUBROUTINE UpdateContinuumState(iTask,iArray,posc,dof,dof_k,nodedof,elm,bmtrx,&
                    detjac,w,mtrlprops,demtrx,dt,stress,strain,effstrain,&
                    effstress,aa,fi,errmsg)

    IMPLICIT NONE

    !I/O
    INTEGER(4) :: iTask, errmsg
    INTEGER(4) :: iArray(64)
    INTEGER(4),DIMENSION(iArray(15),iArray(15),iArray(5)) :: posc
    INTEGER(4),DIMENSION(iArray(22),iArray(21)+1) :: nodedof
    INTEGER(4),DIMENSION(iArray(29),iArray(3)+2) :: elm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(14)) :: dof, dof_k
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(12)*iArray(17),iArray(15)*iArray(5)) :: bmtrx
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(5)*iArray(17)) :: detjac
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(17)) :: w
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(23),iArray(19)) :: mtrlprops
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(8),iArray(8),iArray(23)) :: demtrx
    REAL(8) :: dt
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(2,iArray(12)*iArray(17)*iArray(5)) :: stress
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(12)*iArray(17)*iArray(5)) :: strain
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(2,iArray(17)*iArray(5)) :: effstrain, effstress
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(25)) :: aa
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(14)) :: fi 

    !Locals
    INTEGER(4) :: i, e, mtrl, i1, i2, j1, j2, k1, k2, dim, planetype, elmnodes, &
        Nec, elmpnodes, Ndisp, Nstr, Ncomp, Ngpt, Ndofelm
    INTEGER(4),DIMENSION(iArray(15)) :: doflist
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(12)*iArray(17),iArray(15)) :: belm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(17)) :: jelm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(12)*iArray(17)*iArray(5)) :: dstrain
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(12)*iArray(17)) :: s
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(17)) :: ep, es, dep
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(15),iArray(15)) :: kelm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(iArray(15)) :: felm

    dim       = iArray(1)
...
```

And it fails before the last line above.

Comment: Do you have large local variables -- temporary arrays of significant size, say -- defined for use within routine_one?

Comment: There are a few subroutines called with in that routine, yes. But they are only called one at a time, and each of the locals there are very small compared to the big arrays in the main.

Comment: Also, I set a brakepoint at the first executable line in routine_one and it fails before it reaches that.

Comment: Do you have large routines defined _somewhere_ which aren't defined as allocatable -- that is, fixed size?    Somewhere there's a large amount of data being defined on the stack, in this context usually local variables, and you're running into problems.  You may need to supply more code, or run the code through a debugger and find out where exactly the error is occuring.  Note that the stack size is much smaller than the amount of total memory available, and so a few MB may be enough.

Comment: So it fails _after_ the call to routine_one, but _before_ the first executable statement of the routine?  Ok; can you post the complete set of local variable declarations, etc, for that routine?

Comment: Ok, so it looks to me like belm and dstrain are getting up there with bmtrx in size.    As a simple test, can you give those the `save` attribute (eg, `real(8),save,dimension...`) and see if you get further?  If that doesn't work, with ifort you can be more drastic and put *everything* on the heap; in linux it's with the flag `-heap-arrays`, under windows I guess it would be something like `/heap-arrays`.   If that works, then at least you know what the underlying problem is.  The big local arrays could be dealt with by making them save, or allocating them explicitly.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi Fist and foremost; Thanks for all the help! I tried the save attribute but now my compiler is bothering me. It claims an automatic object (?) must not appear in a save statement or be declared with the save attribute. To be honest, I have no idea what that means. Never used save before. You are right about dstrain being quite big. You think the error happens when I try to allocate the locals in the subroutine?

Comment: Yes, and I see what it means about the save attribute.  The problem is that the arrays I pointed out are sized at runtime, depending on the values in iarray.  So it can't save those - I should have seen that, my appologies.   The alternative would be to make them allocatable and allocate them -- but first, can you try the /heap-arrays option to the compiler and see if that makes the problem go away?  If it does, then we can focus on dealing with the particular arrays which are causing problems.

Comment: Ok, it is getting late here in Sweden and my head is spinning from all these new insights (funny, I actually thought I had a pretty good grasp of the Fortran basics). Will go another round with this tomorrow. Btw, how do I indicate that comments from a particular user was helpful?

Comment: @Jonathan The heap-arrays fix worked! Now I set it so all arrays are allocated/stored (?) to the heap. I guess I could find an accetable limit on size above which an array should be put on the heap instead of the stack? Is CPU-time an issue with this? The pre-processing actually took 12 seconds less now (501 instead of 513) - fluke?

Comment: It could save time if you call a _lot_ of routines; I wouldn't normally expect a significant change one way or the other.   If this works, I'd say that the large local arrays are definately the problem.   My suggestion would be to go after some of the larger local arrays and make them allocatable and allocate them; that will put them on the heap as well, but in a way which doesn't depend on compiler-specific flags.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi: could you somehow put the heap array solution in an answer below?  The solution is a bit hidden in all the comments now.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi I made the large local arrays ALLOCATABLE and used the SAVE option, but that did not work. I get the same error at the same place in the program. I also tried to put only the arrays of 100kB or bigger onto the heap instead of the stack - works just fine. I am having some problems with the program behaving erratic and failing to converge when trying to solve the larger problem, which is annoying, but I guess unrelated to the stack overflow issue.

Comment: Edit: Above comment was not entierly true I realize. It did fail with the ALLOCATABLE and SAVE, but not exactly at the same line as before. It failed at the ALLOCATE(all the larger arrays) line a bit further down. Sorry for that - my bad. Once I removed the SAVE it works. Guess it tried to allocate saved arrays, but they were of course already there on the second pass into the subroutine...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per steabert's request, I'll just summarize the conversation in the comments here where it's a bit more visible, even though M.S.B.'s answer already gets right to the nub of the problem.

In technical programming, where procedures often have large local arrays for intermediate computation, this happens a lot.  Local variables are generally stored on the stack, which typically (and quite reasonably) a small fraction of overall system memory -- usually of order 10MB or so.   When the local variable sizes exceed the stack size, you see exactly the symptoms described here -- a stack overflow occuring after a call to the relevant subroutine but before its first executable statement.

So when this problem happens, the best thing to do is to find the relevant large local variables, and decide what to do.   In this case, at least the variables belm and dstrain were getting quite sizable.

Once the variables are located, and you've confirmed that's the problem, there's a few options.   As MSB points out, if you can make your arrays smaller, that's one option.  Alternatively, you can make the stack size larger; under linux, that's done with `ulimit -s [newsize]`.   That really just postpones the problem, though, and you have to do something different on windows machines.

The other class of ways to avoid this problem is not to put the large data on the stack, but in the rest of memory (the "heap").   You can do that by giving the arrays the `save` attribute (in C, `static`); this puts the variable on the heap and thus makes the values persistent between calls.   The downside there is that this potentially changes the behavior of the subroutine, and means the subroutine can't be used recursively, and similarly is non-threadsafe (if you're ever in a position where multiple threads will enter the routine simulatneously, they'll each see the same copy of the local varaiable and potentially overwrite each other's results).  The upside is that it's easy and very portable -- it should work everywhere.    However, this will only work with fixed-size local variables; if the temporary arrays have sizes that depend on the inputs, you can't do this (since there'd no longer be a single variable to save; it could be different size every time the procedure is called).

There are compiler-specific options which put all arrays (or all arrays of larger than some given size) on the heap rather than on the stack; every Fortran compiler I know has an option for this.   For ifort, used in the OPs post, it's `-heap-arrays` in linux, or `/heap-arrays` for windows.   For gfortran, this may actually be the default.  This is good for making sure you know what's going on, but it means you have to have different incantations for every compiler to make sure your code works.

Finally, you can make the offending arrays allocatable.   Allocated memory goes on the heap; but the variable which points to them is on the stack, so you get the benefits of both approaches.  Also, this is completely standard fortran and so totally portable.   The downside is that it requires code changes.  Also, the allocation process can take nontrivial amounts of time; so if you're going to be calling the routine zillions of times, you may notice this slows things down slightly. (This possible performance regression is easy to fix, though; if you'll be calling it zillions of times with the same size arrays, you can have an optional argument to pass in a pre-allocated local array and use that instead, so that you only allocate/deallocate once).

Allocating/deallocating each time would look like:

```
SUBROUTINE UpdateContinuumState(iTask,iArray,posc,dof,dof_k,nodedof,elm,bmtrx,&
                    detjac,w,mtrlprops,demtrx,dt,stress,strain,effstrain,&
                    effstress,aa,fi,errmsg)

    IMPLICIT NONE

    !...arguments.... 


    !Locals
    !...
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(:,:), allocatable :: belm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(:), allocatable :: dstrain

    allocate(belm(iArray(12)*iArray(17),iArray(15))  
    allocate(dstrain(iArray(12)*iArray(17)*iArray(5))

    !... work

    deallocate(belm)
    deallocate(dstrain)
```

Note that if the subroutine does a lot of work (eg, takes seconds to execute), the overhead from a couple allocate/deallocates should be negligable.  If not, and you want to avoid the overhead, using the optional arguments for preallocated worskpace would look something like:

```
SUBROUTINE UpdateContinuumState(iTask,iArray,posc,dof,dof_k,nodedof,elm,bmtrx,&
                    detjac,w,mtrlprops,demtrx,dt,stress,strain,effstrain,&
                    effstress,aa,fi,errmsg,workbelm,workdstrain)

    IMPLICIT NONE

    !...arguments.... 
    real(8),dimension(:,:), optional, target :: workbelm
    real(8),dimension(:), optional, target :: workdstrain
    !Locals
    !...

    REAL(8),DIMENSION(:,:), pointer :: belm
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(:), pointer :: dstrain

    if (present(workbelm)) then
       belm => workbelm
    else
       allocate(belm(iArray(12)*iArray(17),iArray(15))
    endif
    if (present(workdstrain)) then
       dstrain => workdstrain
    else
       allocate(dstrain(iArray(12)*iArray(17)*iArray(5))
    endif

    !... work

    if (.not.(present(workbelm))) deallocate(belm)
    if (.not.(present(workdstrain))) deallocate(dstrain)
```

Comment: I know it is only anecdotal, but from my tests the method with allocate/deallocate is much faster than putting everything (or just larger arrays) on the heap. Almost a factor 2 in CPU-time difference. Once again @Jonathan Dursi thanks for all the help!

Comment: Code fix following suggestion of rejected (mistakenly, IMHO) edit proposed by @Alberto

Answer (score 4):

Not all of the memory is created when the program starts.  When you call the subroutine the executable is creating the memory that the subroutine needs for local variables.  Typically arrays with simple declarations that are local to that subroutine -- neither allocatable, nor pointer -- are allocated on the stack.   You could have simply run of of stack space when you reached these declarations.   You might have reached a 2GB limit on a 32-bit OS with some array.   Sometimes executable statements implicitly create a temporary array on the stack.

Possible solutions: 1) make your arrays smaller (not attractive), 2) make the stack larger), 3) some compilers have options to switch from placing arrays on the stack to dynamically allocating them, similar to the method used for "allocate", 4) identify large arrays and make them allocatable.

Answer (score 2):

The stack is the memory area where the information needed to return from a function, and the information locally defined in a function is stored.  So a stack overflow may indicate you have a function that calls another function which in its turn calls another function, etc.

I am not familiar with Fortran (anymore) but another cause might be that those functions declare tons of local variables, or at least variables that need a lot of place.

A last one: the stack is typically rather small, so it's not a priori relevant how much memory the machine has.  It should be quite simple to instruct the linker to increase the stack size, at least if you are certain it's just a lack of space, and not a bug in your application.

Edit: do you use recursion in your program?  Recursive calls can eat through the stack very quickly.

Edit: have a look [at this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-increased-stack-usage-of-80-or-higher-compilers-causes-segmentation-fault/): (emphasis mine)

> On Windows, the stack space to
>   reserved for the program is set using
>   the /Fn compiler option, where n is
>   the number of bytes.  Additionally,
>   the stack reserve size can be
>   specified through the Visual Studio
>   IDE which adds the Microsoft Linker
>   option /STACK: to the linker command
>   line.  To set this, go to Property
>   Pages>Configuration
>   Properties>Linker>System>Stack Reserve
>   Size. There you can specify the stack
>   size in bytes in either decimal or
>   C-language notation. If not specified,
>   **the default stack size is 1MB**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Nope, no recursion. I'll see what I can find on increasing the stack size.

Comment: @Carl do you use GNU Fortran and ld?

Comment: No, the intel fortran compiler and Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that earlier on today. What is strange is that I can, without any problem what so ever, run problems of about half the size of the current problem.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I ran into with a similar test code, is the 2Gb allocation limit for 32-bit compilation. When I exceed it I get an error message on line 419 in winsig.c

[image: 2GB Allocation Limit Error]

Here is the test code

```
program FortranCon

implicit none

! Variables
INTEGER :: IA(64), S1
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: AA, BB
REAL(4) :: S2
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N = 10960
IA(1)=N
IA(2)=N

ALLOCATE( AA(N,N), BB(N,N) )
AA(1:N,1:N) = 1D0
BB(1:N,1:N) = 2D0

CALL TEST(AA,BB,IA)

S1 = SIZEOF(AA)                 !Size of each array
S2 = 2*DBLE(S1)/1024/1024       !Total size for 2 arrays in Mb

WRITE (*,100) S2, ' Mb'         ! When allocation reached 2Gb then
100 FORMAT (F8.1,A)                 ! exception occurs in Win32

DEALLOCATE( AA, BB )

end program FortranCon


SUBROUTINE TEST(AA,BB,IA)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, DIMENSION(64),INTENT(IN) :: IA    
REAL(8), DIMENSION(IA(1),IA(2)),INTENT(INOUT) :: AA,BB

... !Do stuff with AA,BB        
END SUBROUTINE
```

When `N=10960` it runs ok showing `1832.9 Mb`. With `N=11960` it crashes. Of course when I compile with x64 it works ok. Each array has 8*N^2 bytes storage. I don't know if it helps but I recommend using the `INTENT()` keywords for the dummy variables.

Comment: Ok, but that is an issue with the limit on the size of a single array I suppose? My largest array is about a 100 times smaller than that. Can I use the INTENT ketwords without writing explicit INTERFACE sections? If so, I agree that that seems like a good practice. I did use that for a while but it got a little bulky with all the INTERFACE I had to keep updated once I changed something.

Comment: You shouldn't need to write interfaces except for special cases, such as calling other languages ... it is better to put your procedures into modules and then "use" the module from the main program or other procedures that use them.   This will catch interface inconsistencies, a common bug.   It is easy and will shorten the development cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using some parallelization? This can be a problem with statically declared arrays. Try all bigger arrays make ALLOCATABLE, otherwise, they will be placed on the stack in autoparallel or OpenMP threads.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the stack reserve size. I went and changed the stack reserved size from `0` to `100000000` and recompiled the code. The code now runs smoothly.

[image]