# Big array problem

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a code that worked fine until now with 3 million atom-sized static arrays.
For practical reasons, I have to go now to 10 million atom sized arrays. At first, my compiler did not allow me to do this, but I managed to find a way around with the following flags `ifort -mcmodel medium -shared-intel -traceback kubo.f`. It runs, but something very strange is happening. My matrix contains 11 609 198 elements.

I check the value of my coordinates as follows (the value of 4 669 671 is the first time it goes wrong):

> print*, x(4669671),y(4669671),zcoord(4669671)

followed by several lines where the value of x, y and zcoord is not changed or anything. Then, I enter a loop on these 3 vectors where the value of x, y and zcoord will be used but not changed. I print the 3 values again, and suddenly, the 3 values are changed?!

Is there something I'm missing for large arrays?

EDIT : Here the complete code (as I don't know what is a race condition, I don't know If I'm allowed to delete some parts to make it more readable) :

> ```
>   open(1,FILE='fort.10')
>   read(1,*)NAT1
>   write(*,*)'Lecture de Nat1=',NAT1
>   read(1,*) 
>   do i=1,nsites
>    read(1,*)parcon(i),x(i),y(i),zcoord(i)
>   enddo
>   print*, x(4663659),y(4663659),zcoord(4663659)
>   print*, x(4663663),y(4663663),zcoord(4663663)
>   !HERE
>   print*, x(4669671),y(4669671),zcoord(4669671)
>   print*, x(4673254),y(4673254),zcoord(4673254)
>   iflag=0
>   iflagg=0
>   impurityCounter=0
>   C4Counter=0
>   do i=1,nsites                                                                                                   
>     nvo=0
>     if(i.le.(nsites-93998)) then                                                                                  
>       jj=i-10000
>       jjj=i+10000
>       do j=jj,jjj,1
>         if((j.gt.0).and.(j.le.(nsites-93998))) then                                                               
>           dist=dsqrt((x(j)-x(i))**2+(y(j)-y(i))**2                                                                
>  .                      +(zcoord(j)-zcoord(i))**2)                                                                
>           if((dist.lt.(1.11*aCC))
>  .             .and.(j.ne.i).and.(dist.gt.0.1)) then                                                              
>              nvo=nvo+1
>              v(i,nvo)=j
>              if(i.eq.4663660) then
>                 !THERE
>                 print*, dist,j,x(j),y(j),zcoord(j)                                                                
>              endif                                                                                                
>           endif                                                                                                   
>         endif                                                                                                     
>       enddo
>       jjjj=nsites-93998+1                                                                                         
>       do j=jjjj,nsites,1
>         dist=dsqrt((x(j)-x(i))**2+(y(j)-y(i))**2                                                                  
>  .                 +(zcoord(j)-zcoord(i))**2)
>         if((dist.lt.(1.11*aCC)).and.(j.ne.i).and.(dist.gt.0.1)) then                                              
>           nvo=nvo+1
>           v(i,nvo)=j                                                                                              
>         endif                                                                                                     
>       enddo                                                                                                       
>     else 
>       do j=1,nsites
>         dist=dsqrt((x(j)-x(i))**2+(y(j)-y(i))**2                                                                  
>  .                 +(zcoord(j)-zcoord(i))**2)
>         if((dist.lt.(1.11*aCC)).and.(j.ne.i).and.(dist.gt.0.1)) then                                              
>           nvo=nvo+1
>           v(i,nvo)=j                                                                                              
>         endif                                                                                                     
>       enddo                                                                                                       
>     endif
>     if ((nvo.eq.2).AND.(parcon(i).eq.'C')) then                                                                   
>       iflag=iflag+1                                                                                               
>       vpb(iflag)=i                                                                                                
>     endif                                                                                                                
>     if((nvo.eq.1).AND.(parcon(i).eq.'C')) then                                                                    
>       iflagg=iflagg+1                                                                                             
>       vpbb(iflagg)=i                                                                                              
>     endif
>     !count the number of impurities
>     if((nvo.eq.2).AND.(parcon(i).eq.'O1')) then                                                                   
>       impurityCounter=impurityCounter+1                                                                           
>       impurityVector(impurityCounter)=i                                                                           
>     endif
>     if((nvo.eq.2).AND.(parcon(i).eq.'O2')) then                                                                   
>       impurityCounter=impurityCounter+1                                                                           
>       impurityVector(impurityCounter)=i                                                                           
>     endif
>     !If nvo equals 4, there is a BAD counting!                                                                           
>     if(nvo.eq.4) then
>         print*, v(i,1)                                                                                            
>         print*, v(i,2)                                                                                            
>         print*, v(i,3)                                                                                            
>         print*, v(i,4)
>         print*, x(i), y(i)                                                                                        
>     endif                                                                                                                
>     if(nvo.eq.5) then
>       C4Counter=C4Counter+1                                                                                       
>       C4Vector(C4Counter)=i                                                                                       
>     endif                                                                                                         
>   enddo
> ```

I added !HERE and !THERE to show you where are the two places I print the x, y and zcoord of the element 4669671...

Comment: Could be a race condition or something similar...can you post the whole code (from printing to printing)?

Comment: what if nvo gets larger than 5? you don't check for that and it's not unlikely from seeing the code that this could happen...  nvo is conditionally increased in your first loop (`nvo=nvo+1`) and when it's larger than 5, the assignment `v(i,nvo)=j` goes out of bounds.  You should check before the assignment if nvo is larger than 5.

Comment: @steabert. I feel stupid. The atomic positions making up the file to be read prohibit having `nvo` larger than 5. At least, that was the case. This time, I made a mistake in writing the atomic positions, and actually, `v(i,nvo)` is getting out of bounds repeatedly. My arrogance made me believe I did not have to check this explicitly. Thanks for the advise. Let's see if it works now. And I'll accept the answer on the -check bounds flag, as it is closest to my question the way it was asked, if that's ok with you. Even though it's your advice that helped me most in the end :)

Comment: And thanks all for your precious help. Probably, it was related to some stupid mistake of mine, but at least, I've learn things on the stack, heap, and how to have data being changed without directly modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ifort, but I assume it has an option for checking array bounds. Turn it on.
Variables changing their value without you actually assigning something to them are often a sign that some other variable is referenced outside of its declared bounds.

Comment: I added -check bounds and I'll keep you updated once it got there. Should be about 1 hour or so...

Comment: +1; if values are changing without you changing them, overwriting memory is a common cause.  If ifort's bounds checking doesn't see anything, I'd try valgrind next.    The obvious array which could be overwritten is v; have you checked to make sure nvo never gets too large?

Comment: Hum... using -CB (or -check bounds), it compiles, but it does not allow me to execute the executable anymore (interactive run returns `Killed`). Does that mean there IS an array bound error?

Comment: @Jonathan. I'm trying to install and use valgrind. I guess it must work for fortran too if you advised it. Just wondering, coz the website only mentions C...

Comment: It'll tell you if something is going on, but it won't give you the same level of diagnostics, this is sadly true.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get any error message besides "killed"?   Maybe with bounds checking the memory usage is once again too large.  A common problem with large arrays is exceeding the available stack space ... see [Stack overflow in Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795938/stack-overflow-in-fortran90).  How are the variables declared?  Are all the integers at least four bytes to hold these large values?   If you are overwriting memory from exceeding an array bound in this block of code, it has to be from storage to an array in this block (v as suggested by @Jonathan Dursi, vpb, vpbb) ... obvious, but you can insert your own index checking code if the compiler option bounds checking still results in an executable that is too large.  Place an IF statement before each array assignment in the code that is executed from before to after the problem occurs.

Comment: Following your link, I submitted a job using the extra -heap-arrays flag. We'll see what it gives. And to answer your questions : arrays are declared using the old fortran77 conventions... for arrays, `DOUBLE PRECISION v(nsites,5)` with the preceding `PARAMETER(nsites=11609198)`, or `INTEGER impurityVector(93998)` without using a parameter. But a quick googlecheck tells me INTEGERS are by default INTEGER*4, so they should be 4 bytes, no?

Comment: Putting the arrays on the heap instead of the stack does not solve my problem. Similarly, I thought maybe because nsites was a PARAMETER which was not explicitly declared as an INTEGER, the error may be there. I did a test declaring it as INTEGER, but to no good luck.